# Tox causing errors with flask render_template (Python)

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, tox

I have ran into an issue with rendering templates. Basically flask can find the template just fine, but tox cannot when ran:

```html
TemplateNotFound: folder_a/file_a.html
```

I am trying to unit test a view that renders a template:

```python
@flask_blueprint_name.route('/')
def hello():
  return render_template('folder_a/file_a.html')
```

The file directory is as follows:
/folder_a/views.py <- This contains the hello function
/templates/folder_a/file_a.html <- This contains the template

The flask installation can find the template and displays it correctly, however running tox -r cannot find the template and i get the above error. Please help me test functions with render_template...

Comment: I can't remote debug this for you, but I can assure you with 99.9% certainty that it has nothing to do with tox (I also have several flask apps using blueprints and test them with pytest/tox - so this is very likely not the problem.

Comment: fixed it by editing the tox.ini file to include the static non .py folders

Comment: Ok - but you may want to look into https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html - this is about packaging - not tox.